# SignalR hang with external model class

Tags: c#, asp.net, model, signalr

I have a very simple SignalR hub and noticed hangs on the hub whenever I try to move my model classes to a class library. Whenever I leave the Model classes in the ASP.net project it works fine and retrieves the objects from the server but once I move the Model class to a class library (for reuse across projects) the SignalR call from the client (js side) hangs. I can see the request makes it to the hub by setting a breakpoint but after that it doesn't return on the clientside.. Any clues here?

I have enabled logging on the client side:

```
[16:37:39 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'myHubhub'.
jquery.signalR.min-2.2.0.js:8 [16:37:39 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22myHubhub%22%7D%5D'.
jquery.signalR.min-2.2.0.js:8 [16:37:39 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport starting.
jquery.signalR.min-2.2.0.js:8 [16:37:39 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://localhost:1275/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProt…VWFxHpWoC0T&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22myHubhub%22%7D%5D&tid=6'.
jquery.signalR.min-2.2.0.js:8 [16:37:39 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource connected.
jquery.signalR.min-2.2.0.js:8 [16:37:39 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport connected. Initiating start request.
jquery.signalR.min-2.2.0.js:8 [16:37:39 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
jquery.signalR.min-2.2.0.js:8 [16:37:39 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000
jquery.signalR.min-2.2.0.js:8 [16:37:39 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)] SignalR: Invoking myHubhub.RetrieveMyObjects
```

Server side hub method:

```
public IEnumerable<MyModel> RetrieveMyObjects()
{
    using (DatabaseContext dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("RetrieveMyObjects()");
        List<MyModel> objs = dbContext.MyObjects.ToList();
        return objs;
    }
}
```

Client side invocation:

```
@section scripts
{        
    <script>       
        $(function () {           
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.myHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
            chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
                // Add the message to the page.
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name)
                    + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
            };
            $.connection.hub.logging = true;
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

                // Call the Send method on the hub.
                chat.server.retrieveMyObjects().done(function (result) {
                    console.log("yep");
                    //Process logic
                }).fail(function (err) {
                    console.log('Could not Connect! ' + err);
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

Comment: Are u using any kind of session with signalr ?

Comment: Nope, I just took the chat example from the signalR site and put in my own model. Works fine if the model class resides inside the asp.net project. Soon as I move it into the external class library it hangs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm I started to strip down my model and found the aswer. I had an enum property marked with "[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]" to serialize the enum to a string value. This apparently breaks some things whenever the model is in an external class lib?

**Edit:**
Problem: External class lib referenced Netwonsoft.Json 7.0.0 and my ASP.NET project refenced version 6.0.4.. Once I downgraded Netwonsoft.Json to 6.0.4 on the class lib everything worked as expected.

Comment: sounds good that u were able to fix. So the net result is that there was some issue with the code which caused exception and signal r started to hang. Right ?

Comment: Yeah I guess so, but the weird thing is no exception popped up in Visual Studio and no errors were logged to the client and server SignalR logs :/